# Basicity of anions

Tags: acid-base

> Which one of the following is strongest base?
>
> **A**. $\ce{Cl-}$
> **B**. $\ce{Br-}$
> **C**. $\ce{I-}$
> **D**. $\ce{CH3COO-}$

Someone please tell me the answer with proper reason.
First I thought that it's $\ce{Cl-},$ but then it clicks in my mind that it's  $\ce{CH3COO-}$ since it's a conjugate base of a weak acid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually got it! The proper way to get to the (right) answer is to ask yourself which one is the conjugate base of a weak acid. If you are given more than one weak acid, you should be provided with the respective acid dissociation constants $K_\mathrm{a}$. In that case, keep in mind that the smaller (i.e. the closer to zero) the $K_\mathrm{a},$ the stronger the acid.